# TSQL escape period in attribute name when using FOR JSON PATH

Tags: json, t-sql

I am using FOR JSON PATH in SQL Server to format JSON.
I would like one of the attribute names in the result object to contain a period '.'

For example, consider this query:

```
SELECT A.tag AS [@odata.etag]
    ,A.val AS [val]
FROM (VALUES('1111', 2222))A(tag,val)
FOR JSON PATH
```

This results in the following output:

```
[
    {
        "@odata": {
            "etag": "1111"
        },
        "val": 2222
    }
]
```

I would like the output formated as:

```
[
    {
        "@odata.etag": "1111",
        "val": 2222
    }
]
```

Is it possible to escape the period in the attribute name?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SQL Server, you could try using [`FOR JSON AUTO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-json-output-automatically-with-auto-mode-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16) in place of `FOR JSON PATH`. It will avoid you to create nested paths in your output json.

```
SELECT A.tag AS '@odata.etag'
     , A.val AS [val]
FROM VALUES('1111', 2222) A(tag,val)
FOR JSON AUTO
```

**Output**:

```
[{"@odata.etag":"1111","val":2222}]
```

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/mUVVVM-Y).

For further information, check how to [Format Query Results as JSON with FOR JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16) in SQL Server.

Comment: This is part of a larger query where I must use FOR JSON PATH. I tried FOR JSON AUTO in a subselect, but it turns the result into escaped json.

Comment: Not sure if escaping inside the FOR JSON PATH can be done at all. Maybe you can work the json out in pieces... As a general recommendation, I'd update the post with a full sample, to satisfy the [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) completeness property.